# What is the correct usage of "deems fit" phrase?

Tags: usage

I want to convey the feeling that "do whatever you feel is the best"? How should I incorporate the phrase "deems fit" in my sentence?

Comment: Do whatever you deem fit.

Comment: And not something like "Do whatever that deems fit to you"?

Comment: Using "deem fit" is very old fashioned.There's nothing wrong with your original sentence, no matter what the context is.

Comment: @Mick - But isn't it sound more formal? I mean my original sentence sounds too dismissive, doesn't it?

Comment: Why? It's perfectly good modern English (and neutral in tone). Depending on how it is said, it could be dismissive or highly encouraging. If you want to use Victorian English, it's up to you. @TomB has the right usage. I wish people would stop obsessing about "formal" English.

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre - "Deem" is like "decide".  *You* deem *something else* fit.  Something else doesn't "deem fit to you".

Comment: @Mick - Thanks for the suggestion. By the way, does Victorian English mean "old fashioned" English(as your first comment says)?

Comment: @stangdon - Does that mean "Do whatever that deems fit to you" is totally wrong?

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre - That's correct.  "Do whatever that deems fit to you" makes no sense.

Comment: As for "whatever deems fit to you" I think you may be reading someone's typo or substituting your own for "whatever **seems** fit to you" (although there are problems with that as well).

Comment: **deem fit** is formal, something of a legalism. If you wish to put the onus onto the other person or entity, you tell them to do as they deem fit.  To "deem" is to make a judgment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mick mentions in his comment, "to deem fit" is a little old-fashioned [but not, I think, enough that you shouldn't learn how to use the idiom.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=deem+fit%2C+deems+fit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)  I wouldn't call it "Victorian" English, as it's a phrase that sees regular use even today.

This answer by Tom B is the best rephrase of your sentence.

> Do whatever you deem fit

Other examples:

> Pick whichever person you deem fit for the job.
>
> My path is mine to walk as I deem fit.
>
> This plan of creating an electoral college to select the president was expected to secure the choice by the best citizens of each state, in a tranquil and deliberate way, of the man whom they in their unfettered discretion should deem fittest to be the chief magistrate of the Union.

"Deem" is itself a verb meaning "to judge" or "to consider (in a specified way)".  You can, conceivably, *deem* anything but it's a word that is more commonly associated with words like "necessary" or "proper", or used alone:

> It's clever enough, but the question is whether future generations will deem it "art".
>
> Jackson spoke, relating all he deemed pertinent.
>
> I am trying to make a point about the fuzzy edges of what has been deemed a "disease".

Comment: I'd go along with that. It's a usage that's worth learning about -- enough so that you can make an informed decision about when to use it.

Comment: Today, it would probably be: do as you **see** fit.